How to always show scrollbar using RawScrollbar in Flutter
I have an app with a single vertical RawScrollbar and multiple horizontal RawScrollbars. For consistency, I would like to always show the Scrollbar for the horizontal Scrollbars even if scrolling is not needed, because IMO it looks better when scrolling because it is consistent. I could not find a way to do that with the component settings, so to solve that, I made the width exceed the screen width and the Scrollbar shows. It solves my problem, but I thought I’d enquire if there is another simple way to achieve that.
